# How should I obtain the fractional part of a floating-point value?

Tags: c, floating-point, c99, floor, libm

I have a variable `x` of type `float`, and I need its fractional part. I know I can get it with

- `x - floorf(x)`, or
- `fmodf(x, 1.0f)`

My questions: Is one of these always preferable to the other? Are they effectively the same? Is there a third alternative I might consider?

Notes:

- If the answer depends on the processor I'm using, let's make it x86_64, and if you can elaborate about other processors that would be nice.
- Please make sure and refer to the behavior on negative values of `x`. I don't mind this behavior or that, but I need to know what the behavior is.

Comment: At least the answer shouldn't depend on the processor.

Comment: I'd never heard of fmod(), so I had to play with it. When the source number is zero or less, the results are different. Does this matter?

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a third alternative I might consider?

There's the dedicated function for it. [modff](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/modf) exists to decompose a number into its integral and fractional parts.

> `float modff( float arg, float* iptr );`
>
> Decomposes given floating point value `arg` into integral and fractional
> parts, each having the same type and sign as `arg`. The integral part
> (in floating-point format) is stored in the object pointed to by `iptr`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that `x - floorf(x)` is pretty good (exact), except in corner cases

- it has the wrong sign bit for negative zero or any other negative whole float
  (we might expect the fraction part to wear the same sign bit).
- it does not work that well with inf

modff does respect -0.0 sign bit for both int and frac part, and answer +/-0.0 for +/-inf fraction part - at least if implementation supports the IEC 60559 standard (IEEE 754).
A rationale for inf could be: since every float greater than 2^precision has a null fraction part, then it must be true for infinite float too.

That's minor, but nonetheless different.

**EDIT** Err, of course as pointed by @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the most obvious flaw of `x - floor(x)` is for the case of negative floating point with a fraction part, because applied to -2.25, it would return +0.75 for example, which is not what we expect...

Since c99 label is used, `x - truncf(x)` would be more correct, but still suffer from the minor problems onto which I initially focused.

Comment: For negative `x` `floorf` will be the closest integer less than `x`. So for say `-3.2` we will get `-4.0` which will in turn produce `-3.2 - (-4.0) = 0.8` - which is not just the wrong sign.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Arghh, thanks for pointing this, I was so much focused on the sign of zero fraction part, that I missed the most obvious problem!